# Convert Apache config to Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

Does anybody know online tools to convert Apache config to Nginx?

I am moving my app to Docker (next step K8s) and this app currently is using Apache.
I have a lot of issues related to Apache, so I decided to try to use Nginx.

It is much simpler to configure it, but now I need to convert site config file.
Does anybody can help with this?

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
...
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    Require all granted

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} mlcas/login.php
    RewriteRule mlcas/login.php(.*)$ /login/$1 [L,R=301]
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) /portal-site/$1 [L]
</Directory>

<Files "request.html">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, accept"
</Files>

<Directory "/var/www/html/core/api">
    Options +Includes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/portals>
    RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/index.php(.*)$ /storage_p/master_portal/index.php$1
    RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/private/?(.*)$ /storage_p/master_portal/private/$1
    RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/scripts/?(.*)$ /storage_p/master_portal/scripts/$1
    RewriteRule ^/?.+Portal/graphics/?(.*)$ /storage_p/master_portal/graphics/$1
</Directory>
```